# How do I add a property to a generic function using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that adds a property to a generic function parameter. (The real code is slightly more complicated and not really worth getting into.)

```
function addProp(func) {
  const newFunc = function (...params) {
    return func.apply(this, params);
  }
  newFunc.prop = 1;
  return newFunc;
}
```

With Flow I could use `[[call]]` to declare the generic as the callable signature of the return type, but TypeScript has no documentation on a similar API. How can I correctly type this in TypeScript?

```js
function addProp<F extends Function>(func: F): {
  // note that [[call]] is not valid TypeScript
  [[call]]: F;
  prop: number;
} {
  const newFunc = function (...params) {
    return func.apply(this, params);
  }
  newFunc.prop = 1;
  return newFunc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With TypeScript you can use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) to combine `F` with a type that contains `prop`:

```js
function addProp<F extends Function>(func: F): F & { prop: number } {
  const newFunc = function (...params) {
    return func.apply(this, params);
  }
  newFunc.prop = 1;
  return newFunc;
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoAoCc4AcA8AYogKYAeUJYqAzooeNPGAHwAUokAXPQJQ-EAZIgDeiXDlw8wIALYAjElkQBfUQChEiCAhpREYEgHcGkRAF5EnJgkRsAdI9zIsyWTV4atWrCSggsJGt7ZFxcABsATzYoAAsYGgAacRc3DwBuTVUswxNGewk8C0QARkyfPwCkXNMITJV1dXC-RF8aEHD9SzRMSTY2ADdkcJASHj0sGDAAc09zFkQAFgAmXkz1No6oNgByZBpUYB21jZJ2zoLJdKA)

---

However, the error you get from this when returning `newFunc` is:

```
Type '((...params: Parameters<F>) => any) & { prop: number; }' is not assignable to type 'F'.
    '((...params: Parameters<F>) => any) & { prop: number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'F', but 'F' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '(...args: any[]) => any'.
```

The last bit is important. While the two types match, `F` could be a subtype of it's constraint causing a problem.

For example much like the output of your function, the input could be a function with additional properties on it. In that case, since you're wrapping it in a new function, those properties would not exist on the returned function anymore.

If you want to convince the compiler that this is ok, I suggest casting the function to `F`:

```js
function addProp<F extends (...args: any[]) => any>(func: F): F & { prop: number } {
  const newFunc = Object.assign(function (...params: Parameters<F>) {
    return func(...params);
  } as F, {prop: 1});
//  ^^^^
  return newFunc;
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoAoCc4AcA8AYogKYAeUJYqAzogBQB0zyWA5jQFwpgCeA2gF0AlIgC8APh68J9UJG6FhixADJEAb0S4cubmBABbAEYksiAL6aAUIkQQENKIjAkA7oXARxiAPLGAKxJoRmQaGhg2MDkvWAQGZkZcVmRDLkQMFMMSSiwaIglRDVs7RCwckCwkeQgmZmSsVJphAG4SqzDEQgAaTR08bgBGC1aS8qhKpFcPLzaLa2sAGxyykhoQRecxFHRsPHp6ADdkRZASbicsGDA2UUlEABYAJlHrcvXN+gByMNRgL9G7w2UCSuh8gxaQA)

Comment: Thanks! This fixes any errors I'd get from accessing the prop, but the internals of the function still has an error on the return. I simplified the example here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoAoCc4AcA8AYogKYAeUJYqAzogBQB0zyWA5jQFwpgCeA2gF0AlIgC8APh68J9UJG6FhixADJEAb0S4cubmBABbAEYksiAL6aAUIkQQENKIjAkA7oXARxiAPLGAKxJoRmQaGhg2MDkvWAQGZkZcVmRDLkQMFMMSSiwaIglRDVs7RCwckCwkeQgmZmSsVJphAG4SiwAaTR08bgBGC1aS8qhKpFcPLzaLa2sAGxyykhoQOecxFHRsPHp6ADdkOZASbicsGDA2UUlEABYAJiHrcpW1+gByMNRgd6GX1agSV0Pj6LSAA

Comment: See the updated answer for an explanation and solution.

Comment: You're totally right, and it looks like adding func as the 2nd param in the assign call fixes the issue as well. http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoAoCc4AcA8AYogKYAeUJYqAzogBQB0zyWA5jQFwpgCeA2gF0AlIgC8APh68J9UJG6FhixADJEAb0S4cubmBABbAEYksiAL6aAUIkQQENKIjAkA7oXARxiAPLGAKxJoRmQaGhg2MDkvWAQGZkZcVmRDLkQMFMMSSiwaIglRDVs7RCwckCwkeQgmZmSsVJphAG4SiwAaRBqujR08bgBGC1aS8qhKpFcPLzaLa2sAGxyykhoQRecxFHRsPHp6ADdkRZASbicsGDA2UUlEABYAJlHrcvXN+gByMNRgL9G7w2UCSuh8gxaQA